# Inverse Laplace Transform of $(s+1)/z^s$

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to compute this ILT
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{s+1}{z^s}\right\},$$
where $|z|>1$. However, I'm not sure this is possile? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $z$ is a complex number, right?

Comment: yes, $z$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd one.  I worked the actual Bromwich integral directly because the residue theorem is no help here.  You get something in terms of $c$, the offset from the imaginary axis of the integration path.  So I appealed to something more basic.  Consider

$$\hat{f}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \: f(t) e^{-s t}$$

Just the plain Laplace transform of some function $f$.  Let's throw away any conditions on continuity, etc. on $f$, and consider

$$f(t) = \delta(t-\log{z})$$

for some $z$.  Then

$$\hat{f}(s) = z^{-s}$$

Interesting. Now consider $f(t) = \delta'(t-\log{z})$; then

$$\hat{f}(s) = s z^{-s} + \delta(-\log{z})$$

It follows that

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\delta(t-\log{z})+ \delta'(t-\log{z})\right\} = \frac{s+1}{z^s} + \delta(-\log{z})$$

Therefore

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{s+1}{z^s}\right\} = \delta(t-\log{z})+ \delta'(t-\log{z}) - \delta(-\log{z}) \delta(t)$$

Comment: thanks for the nice derivation/explanation as I thought the same thing - very odd (+1).

Comment: @Amzoti: thanks.  This one would be a good one to feed to students to test to see if they really remember what an inverse LT is.

Comment: @pbs: what you are saying makes no sense.  The ILT takes a function of $s$ to a function of $t$, unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: @RonGordon How is the Dirac delta function defined here for complex arguments? Since $z$ is complex, we have, for example, $\delta(t-\log z)$, but $t$ is purely real, whereas $\log z$ can be complex. I'm not really sure what $\delta(t - \log z)$ means for complex $z$.

Comment: The point is that we are exploiting the sampling property of the delta function:

$$\int dx \: \delta (x-a) f(x) = f(a)$$

Really nothing more to it than that.

Comment: But according to http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E7%8B%84%E6%8B%89%E5%85%8B%CE%B4%E5%87%BD%E6%95%B0#.E6.80.A7.E8.B4.A8, it seems that $\mathcal{L}\{\delta'(t-\log{z})\}=sz^{-s}$ . Why you claim that $\mathcal{L}\{\delta'(t-\log{z})\}=sz^{-s}+\delta(-\log{z})$ ?

Comment: @doraemonpaul: integration by parts - the $\delta(-\log{z})$ piece corresponds to the evaluation at $t=0$.  Do it out and see.